# Using select inside a count in a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I'm trying to select all the equipments from the revision planning that must be done this month if I didn't make a service sheet for that equipment. I want to do something like this:

```
select revision_planning.id_echip as echip_id
from revision_planning
    inner join service_sheet on echip_id=service_sheet.id_echip
where revision_planning.next_rev_date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31'
  and count (select * from service_sheet 
             where echip_id=service_sheet.id_echip
               and service_sheet.`data`between '2016-10-01 00:00:00'and '2016-10-31 23:59:18') = 0
  and revision_planning.employee_name='first_last_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
select revision_planning.id_echip as echip_id from revision_planning
  inner join service_sheet on echip_id=service_sheet.id_echip
  where revision_planning.next_rev_date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31' and not exists (select 1 from service_sheet 
    where echip_id=service_sheet.id_echip and service_sheet.`data`between '2016-10-01 00:00:00'and '2016-10-31 23:59:18')
 and revision_planning.employee_name='first_last_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS statement instead of checking for COUNT = 0 in WHERE clause

```
select revision_planning.id_echip as echip_id 
from revision_planning
inner join service_sheet on echip_id=service_sheet.id_echip
where revision_planning.next_rev_date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31' 
and NOT EXISTS(select 1 from service_sheet 
where echip_id=service_sheet.id_echip and service_sheet.`data`between '2016-10-01 00:00:00'and '2016-10-31 23:59:18')
and revision_planning.employee_name='first_last_name'
```

Comment: I believe , in not exits `select 1` will be more optimized than `select *`

Comment: Yes but the difference will be noticed if table is big

Comment: @NzGuy: that is a myth that has never been true. There is no performance difference between `select 1` and `select *` for an `exists` condition in any modern DBMS (and never has been - at least not in this millenium)